# Grails : Could not set the value of parameter and kept on getting cannot be null

Tags: hibernate, grails

**Domain Class:**

```
class Employee {
    .
    .
    Boolean syncFlag
    Date dateLastModified 
}
```

**MySQL:**

```
Column name              Data type                    Default value
---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                 
sync_flag                BIT(1)         Not Null      b'0'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

date_last_modified       TIMESTAMP      Not Null      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**Controller:**

```
def save() {      
       .
       .

    params.remove('id')

     if(params.dateLastModified){
        params.remove('dateLastModified')
     }

     if(params.syncFlag){
        params.remove('syncFlag')
     }
```

Hi, I've posted above all the necessary codes that might help you analyze what the problem was. Basically, the error is `syncFlag` and `dateLastModified` cannot be null. So what I did was removed these keys by using

```
params.remove('<column name>')
```

so that in the insert statement of hibernate these will be skipped and since I defined in MySQL that these should not be null, it will use the default value set. The problem is that I kept getting that same error (.... cannot be null). So what I did was set the default value of these in the domain class but it didn't works either. I also tried to hard code it like this:

```
params.syncFlag=false
```

but it also didn't works.

When print the value of those 2 fields, I get null even if I hard coded it already.

I think I've already made everything that I can to debug but all of it failed. Could you tell me what might have caused this and why I'm getting cannot be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might actually think that this is weird but this fixed my problem.

```
Employee employeeInstance = new Employee(params);
employeeInstance.setSyncFlag(false);
employeeInstance.setDateLastModified(new Date());
employeeInstance.save(flush:true)
```

The issue is I had the hard time changing some of the value in params, and i dont know why. So what I did was, before I call save, I changed the value using the setters. And that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain class is set to not allow null properties. That's the Grails default. To allow nulls, use the [nullable](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html) [constraint](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html).

```
class Employee {
    ...
    static constraints = {
        dateLastModified nullable: true
        syncFlag nullable: true
    }
}
```

## Hint

To get a Map without certain keys you can follow this example:

```
def params = [
    id: 100,
    dateLastModified: new Date(),
    syncFlag: true,
    other: "This won't get filtered out"]

def ignore = ['id', 'dateLastModified', 'syncFlag']
assert params.findAll { key, value -> !(key in ignore) } == [other:"This won't get filtered out"]
```

You can filter them out with *findAll()*. Note that by filter I mean the original *params* remains unchanged.

Comment: Or perhaps it would be more consistent to leave these properties as not nullable, but specify their default values in the domain, i.e `dateLastModified = new Date()` and `syncFlag = false`

Comment: Oh definitely. If the parameters should not be nullable, then by all means DON'T make them so in the domain class. @Yaro, have you used your suggestion? I'm asking because I thought I had but it didn't work. But honestly, I just don't remember. I do recall using beforeInsert and beforeUpdate.

Comment: I do use it often. Specifying property values this way works like for any other Java class, they get set when a new domain instance gets created and persisted when the domain instance gets saved, thus acting kinda like default values.